# How to use khan's Academy API for fetching exercises

Tags: khan-academy

Hi I want to use khan academy api calls to integrate its execises on particular topic in my project.So i am using the following api(https://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/exercises/logarithms_1). I want to know how to use the result of this api to display exercises on logarithms_1. it shows ka_url as one link which redirect me to one question on khanacademy page but i want to use the result for a person who submits the answere.

Comment: Hi @shukshum welcome to SO. You need to show your steps before asking a question. This is SO's basic. You can search on Google like I just did ... https://www.google.fr/search?q=khan+academy+api&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=6g5-V-7QGu6v8wfOsqu4CQ 3rd link , the one on git should provide you enough clues to get started

Comment: Hi @Andy i have just hit the API whose url is given. now i just want to know what parameters of that api result can be used to refer to exercises on that topic?

Comment: that's the deal here in SO and when you'll be working in IT. You'll have to figure it out by yourself, most of the time. Time to dig a bit and see how it goes :)